# How to save string with code page 1250 into RandomAccessFile in java

Tags: java, file

I have text file with string which code page is 1250. I want to save text into RandomAccessFile. When I read bytes from RandomAccessFile I get string with different character. Some solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [`writeUTF()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) then you should read its JavaDoc to learn that it always writes [modified UTF-8](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8).

If you want to use another encoding, then you'll have to "manually" do the encoding and somehow store the length of the `byte[]` as well.

For example:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = ...;
String writeThis = ...;
byte[] cp1250Data = writeThis.getBytes("cp1250");
raf.writeInt(cp1250Data.length);
raf.write(cp1250Data);
```

Reading would work similarly:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = ...;
int length = raf.readInt();
byte[] cp1250Data = new byte[length];
raf.readFully(cp1250Data);
String string = new String(cp1250Data, "cp1250");
```

Comment: I'm getting ?ÄŐđŔ×Ü instead of ČŽŠĐčžšđ­.                          `byte[] name = new byte[NAME_LEN];
len = raf.read(name); System.out.println("Name: "+new String(name, "cp1250"));`

Comment: @Gogoo: then this indicates that the file is not in the encoding that you think it is. Where does the file come from? How did you learn about its encoding?

Comment: Yes the file was use encoding 852. Thanks. I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code will write and read a string using the 1250 code page. Of course, you will need to clean it, check exceptions and close streams properly before putting in prod :)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("/toto.txt");
    String myString="This is a test";
    OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), Charset.forName("windows-1250"));
    w.write(myString);
    w.flush();
    CharBuffer b = CharBuffer.allocate((int)file.length());
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), Charset.forName("windows-1250")).read(b);
    System.out.println(b.toString());
}
```